# Finding solution angles that are a fixed distance apart based upon an initial angle set

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

I have three angles between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$ that are all close to being $120^\circ$ apart. E.g. [$50^\circ$, $183^\circ$, $310^\circ$].

How can I mathematically find values that best fit these points but are exactly $120^\circ$ apart? [$50^\circ$, $183^\circ$, $344^\circ$] --> [$55^\circ$, $175^\circ$, $295^\circ$] (this was an example solution and probably not correct)

Comment: Interesting problem. You want the best fit isosceles triangle from thee points, right?

Comment: In such sorts of problems, you have to define what "best" means. What is it that you want to minimize or maximize? Do you want the _maximum_ of the three "deviations" (absolute differences between each given angle and the associated solution angle) to be minimal? Or the _sum_ of the absolute differences? Or the sum of the squares of the differences? We could also try to maximize the sum of the cosines of the differences of the angles... Different objective functions can lead to different results. The choice of the objective function depends on the scenario the solution is required for.

Comment: Haha, yes. That is spot on John.

Comment: Reinhard. That makes total sense. I see that the answer could change depending on the variable that you want to minimize. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

I would find the phase angle needed to rotate an isosceles triangle in order to meet the target angles.

In radians the angles of an isoceles triangle are $ 120° (i-1) = \tfrac{2 \pi}{3} (i-1)$ for $i=1\ldots 3$

Each target angle $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ needs a phase shift of $\varphi$ defined by

$$ \varphi_i =  \theta_i - \tfrac{2\pi}{3} (i-1) - n\, 2\pi $$ for $n=0$ or $n=1$

choose the wraparound integer $n$ such that it makes all three $\varphi$ as close as possible.

Now you can take the average phase shift as a best fit

$$ \varphi = \frac{ \varphi_1 + \varphi_2 + \varphi_3}{3} $$

If all $n=0$ and no wraparound is needed then

$$ \varphi = \frac{ \theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 - 2\pi}{3} $$

But if you need to specify some wraparound integers $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$ which might be 0 or 1 then

$$ \varphi = \frac{ \theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 - 2\pi (1+ n_1 + n_2 + n_3) }{3} $$

For the example in the *op* you have

$$ \varphi = \frac{ 50° + 183° + 295° - 360°}{3} = 56° $$

and find the three angles as

$$ \theta_i' = \varphi +  \tfrac{2\pi}{3} (i-1) $$

for the example above this is

$$ \begin{aligned} \theta_1 &= 56° & \theta_2 & = 176° & \theta_3 & = 296° \end{aligned}$$

---

To find the difference between two angles, without having to worry about wrapping around 360° you do

$$\Delta \phi = \cos^{-1}\left( \cos \left( \phi_1 - \phi_2 \right) \right) $$

this is derived from the dot product of two vectors on the unit circle.

Comment: This is fantastic! Really helpful. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

Sort the angles (no wrapping around). So assuming this, the angle are:
$[x,x+120,x+240]$. Now find $x$ which minimizes $||x[1,1,1]+[0,120,240]-[50,183,310]||$. As one of the comments said, u need to pick a norm $||.||$ to solve this. If the norm is $\ell_2$, then the solution is $x=\frac{(50+(183-120)+(310-240))}{3} = 61$. So for $\ell_2$ norm, ur solution is: $[61,61+120,61+240] = [61,181,301]$. I do not think u need to bother about wrapping around property of angles here as your angles are far away from boundary points $0,360$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize that it was called an ℓ2 norm. This is helpful, thank you for your answer.